# Missiles Range & Speed

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm looking for summary of the values of missiles's speed and ranges, including AA and skills.

PS : The initial debate with my friend was wich skill shot is easier to land beetween Morgana's Dark Binding and Amumu's Bandage Toss and I just founded Morgana 1300 Range at 1200 speed and Amumu 1100 range but can't find the speed, anayway I'm still interested in other speeds//ranges ;-)

Comment: Website recommendations (and really, recommendations in general) don't really work so well for Arqade.  We can probably provide some specific values for you (in this case, Amumu's speed), and hopefully a link to a wiki or something.  I'd recommend re-wording it so it doesn't ask for a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [wikia for league of legends](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki) it tells the projectile speed of a lot of abilities

It does tell for [Amumu's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Amumu) Bandage toss(1800 speed and 1100 range).
and for [morgana's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Morgana) dark binding (1200 speed and 1300 range).